# Material UI - Widget component issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the autocomplete component, and finally, I finished the feature as I wanted but since this component is rendered in other pages as a widget I'm getting some weird issues with the styling since the page that renders my component is overriding/adding styles they have globally.

This is how it looks in my local:
[image]

And this is how it looks when I deploy it and I check it on one of the pages:
[image]
[image]

I've been working on this the whole day without success, but I found that the styles that are braking my component are these ones:

[image]

[image]

I'm using these styles to hide the outlined style of the textfield

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: 'none !important',
      outline: 'none'
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: 'none !important',
      outline: 'none'
    }
  }
}));
```

And this is how my autocomplete components look like

```
<Autocomplete
          id="listings-filter"
          multiple
          disableCloseOnSelect={true}
          freeSolo
          clearOnBlur={false}
          limitTags={5}
          disableCloseOnSelect={true}
          blurOnSelect={false}
          options={options}
          groupBy={(option) => option.key }
          onInputChange={handleInputChange}
          onChange={handleOptionSelection}
          disableCloseOnSelect
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
          renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                checked={selected}
              />
            {option.value}
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              id='autocomplete-input'
              {...params}
              margin={'dense'}
              className={autocompleteClasses.root}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true
              }}
              variant='outlined'
              label="Search listings by address, MLS or property name"
              placeholder='Type the address, MLS or property name'
            />
          )}
        />
```

I tried to add inputProps to the textfield and give the styles there but this didn't work at all, also tried adding the styles on the **makeStyles** part but I'm confused about how to get into the exact class I need with MUI style overrides, and since this looks that is related with generic input component and not with a material UI component, made me confuse even more.
I don't know if this is possible with react or I have to build a CSS file to be able to avoid this behavior. Really appreciate any help!

EDIT:
Also tried using the inputProps of the **TextField** component leaning on another stackoverflow question but that make the autocomplete component to crash when the input is clicked with the following error -> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: 'none !important',
      outline: 'none'
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      border: 'none !important',
      outline: 'none'
    }
  },
  input: {
    border: '10 !important',
    borderColor: 'red',
    boxShadow: 'unset !important',
    color: 'red'
  }
}));

renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              id='autocomplete-input'
              {...params}
              margin={'dense'}
              className={autocompleteClasses.root}
              InputLabelProps={{
                ...params.InputLabelProps,
                shrink: true
              }}
              inputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                classes:{
                  root: autocompleteClasses.input,
                }
              }}
              variant='outlined'
              label="Search listings by address, MLS or property name"
              placeholder='Type the address, MLS or property name'
            />
          )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a scss file:

```
.autocomplete-component > div > div > input {
  border: 0px !important;
  border-color: white !important;
  box-shadow: unset !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: unset !important
}
```

and used as a className on the autocomplete component:

```
import './listingStyles.scss'

<Autocomplete
          id="listings-filter"
          className={'autocomplete-component'}
          multiple
          disableCloseOnSelect={true}
          freeSolo
          clearOnBlur={false}
          limitTags={5}
          disableCloseOnSelect={true}
          blurOnSelect={false}
          options={options}
          groupBy={(option) => option.key }
          onInputChange={handleInputChange}
          onChange={handleOptionSelection}
          disableCloseOnSelect
... />
```

Hope this is useful for anyone!